# Is it possible to embed a dependent clause within an infinitive?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

- To boldly go where no man has gone before.

I think **where no man has gone before** is an dependent clause. But I cannot find its independent clause. Is this sentence correct? If it is correct, please tell how **To boldly go** is related with **where no man has gone before**. If it is possible, please discuss the construction of this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a sentence but an infinitive clause acting as a nominal defining one aspect of the *Enterprise*'s mission. *Where no man has gone before* is a locative complement to the verb *go*, the destination or goal of going, just like *to boldly go **home*** or *to boldly go **around the corner***.

In fact, there is only actual sentence in the *Star Trek* introduction.

> Space, the final frontier. *[not a sentence: a phrase defining the scene]*
>
> These are the voyages of the starship Enterprise.  *[the actual sentence!]*
>
> Its five-year mission: *[not a sentence, but a noun phrase characterizing what follows*]
>
> > to explore strange new worlds, *[an infinitive clause]*
> > to seek out new life and new civilizations, *[an infinitive clause]*
> > to boldly go where no man has gone before. *[an infinitive clause]*

Think of it as a series of captions or headlines.